# pyethapp requirements.txt install fails on "Building wheel for gevent (setup.py) ... - error"

Tags: mac-osx, pyethapp, raiden

OSX 10.15.4

Running under virtual env with python3.7

Hi, I'm trying to work with Raiden.
Trying to install pyethapp.
While installing the requirements.txt, I fail on "Building wheel for gevent (setup.py) ... -   error"

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

`pip install -r ./pyethapp/requirements.txt`

```
.
.
.
Collecting python-dateutil
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e2/83/7c/248063997a4f9ff6bf145822e620e8c37117a6b4c765584077/toolz-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: gevent, leveldb, ethereum-serpent
  **Building wheel for gevent (setup.py) ... -   error**
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/jbalakay/venv37/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1m/j65x_cy522v_vx70c55nl9zh0000gn/T/pip-install-2cq56iwj/gevent/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1m/j65x_cy522v_vx70c55nl9zh0000gn/T/pip-install-2cq56iwj/gevent/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/1m/j65x_cy522v_vx70c55nl9zh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-673iz9v8
       cwd: /private/var/folders/1m/j65x_cy522v_vx70c55nl9zh0000gn/T/pip-install-2cq56iwj/gevent/
  Complete output (237 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_semaphore.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/event.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_util_py2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/signal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_ssl3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/builtins.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/local.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_socketcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/coros.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/os.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_ssl2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_fileobjectcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_socket2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/corecffi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_fileobjectposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_sslgte279.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_socket3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/select.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  copying gevent/_tblib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  running build_ext
  Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/1m/j65x_cy522v_vx70c55nl9zh0000gn/T/pip-install-2cq56iwj/gevent/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/1m/j65x_cy522v_vx70c55nl9zh0000gn/T/pip-install-2cq56iwj/gevent/build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/libev
  building 'gevent.corecext' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/jbalakay/venv37/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c gevent/gevent.corecext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/gevent/gevent.corecext.o
  In file included from gevent/gevent.corecext.c:241:
  In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
  libev/ev.c:483:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
  /*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                                 ^
  libev/ev.c:1692:31: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                                ^
  libev/ev.c:1801:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    if (elem * ncur > MALLOC_ROUND - sizeof (void *) * 4)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  libev/ev.c:3715:34: warning: '&' within '|' [-Wbitwise-op-parentheses]
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
  libev/ev.c:3715:34: note: place parentheses around the '&' expression to silence this warning
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                                   ^
                         (                      )
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2276:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 121; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2268:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 121; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2664:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 144; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2656:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 144; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3141:142: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_3 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_8, __pyx_t_9); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_9++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 171; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L5_error;}
                                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3133:141: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_3 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_8, __pyx_t_9); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_9++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 171; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L5_error;}
                                                                                                                                              ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3440:97: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_6gevent_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_1 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 161; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:435:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                            ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3713:140: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_2 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_5); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_5++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 194; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3705:139: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_2 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_5); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_5++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 194; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3927:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 201; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3919:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 201; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:4678:99: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
      __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_6gevent_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 260; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:435:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                            ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:5161:140: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_6 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 294; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:5153:139: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_6 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 294; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:8323:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_2 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 465; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:8315:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_2 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 465; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45511:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      *type = tstate->exc_type;
              ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45512:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      *value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_value
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45513:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45525:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45526:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45527:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45528:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45529:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45530:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45573:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45574:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45575:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45576:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = local_type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45577:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tstate->exc_value = local_value;
              ^~~~~~~~~
              curexc_value
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45578:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
              curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:46117:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:46118:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          curexc_value
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:240:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:46119:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:241:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:46120:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tstate->exc_type = *type;
      ~~~~~~  ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 warnings and 20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
  Running setup.py clean for gevent
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Pyethapp was archived years ago and it is no longer being maintained.

A new python client is now developed at https://github.com/ethereum/trinity.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to work with Raiden, can I use other clients instead of "pyethapp" for that?

Comment: @user60380 I haven't used raiden yet so I can't say it is compatible with other clients. Check the requirements of pyethapp, it uses python2.7, try to use dependencies when it was being developed 2 or 3 years ago.